# Show the # of Qs asked by individuals besides on A51

Tags: feature-request

Based on the conversation in the comments here: [Improving our Stats](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/improving-our-stats/244#244) is there a way to help us recognize who is contributing by asking questions? Often the experts that know the most answers often know the most good questions as well, and they can provide them to help attract other experts.

Since the number of questions asked is so important during a beta as a way to help drive traffic is there a way to see this stat in a list of users?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest to find those asking the questions, is to look at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4260/database-administrators. You can easily find those asking many questions between those who give many answers.

On the other side on SO I have 20 questions 121 answers.
Here I have 48 answers to 37 questions.

And the pattern of my questions is changing, I'm no more trying to think up interesting questions.

Most questions I'm posing now, are directly influenced by some more or less urgent problem at work or questions from coworker I just pass throw.

I found that I often get answers in a short very time. But I'm a database developer, I don't have to teach people, I just can focus on solving problems.

I guess it is better, when I try to optimize my questions with respect to search engines.
In fact in some cases it is easier for me, to find my questions by google, than to find file on my local machine.

BTW I think our problem is the low number of questions, what would it help to encourage experts to write more answers.

I you would wish me more problems to solve at work, that would have better influence on the stats.( LOL )

Comment: Yup, the stats are the on A51 - we were wondering if they could be displayed on the main [users page](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users)

Comment: They are looking for a page on the main-site that duplicates the report given on A51 in a smaller format

Comment: Not having interesting Qs is a problem a lot of us with more knowledge have, as the As we know are generally, to us, obvious at this point, as the Qs are no longer interesting. But that's a different problem, and not altogether related to this ;)